# Why is my dataframe using column names I did not assign?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a dataframe that is a subset of another dataframe, but I want the column names changed. I know that this can be done by using the names() or colnames() functions, but I would like to do the name change as the dataframe is created.

```
temp2<- data.frame(
    'year' = (ncdata[,'year'] + 1),
    'report' = (ncdata[,'report'] + 1),
    'prev_period_last_year' = ncdata[,'received']
  )
```

I would expect temp2 to contain 3 columns with names (year, report, and prev_period_last_year). Instead of this, the third column in temp2 just uses the original name 'received' from ncdata. Why is this happening?

EDIT: In response to comments, I have tried omitting the quotation marks in the dataframe declaration, and I have tried using the numerical index of desired ncdata columns rather than the column name. Neither change has had any effect.

Comment: I can't test right away so I'll leave a comment Why do you need the quotes?Did you try to just use Year=your data. Report=your data.?

Comment: Have you tried indexing with numbers?

Comment: @NelsonGon, I was under the impression that the quotes were a necessary syntax, but I just ran the code again without them and nothing changed.

Comment: Check to see if my answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Follow this kind of syntax

```
data1<-data.frame(Year=c(2017,2016,2019),Received=c(340,560,780))
data1
data.frame(Test=data1[,1]+1,Test1=data1[,2]+1)
```

Result:

```
 Test Test1
1 2018   341
2 2017   561
3 2020   781
```

This also works:

```
data.frame(Testme=data1[,"Year"]+1)
  Testme
1   2018
2   2017
3   2020
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of your data with `dput`?

Comment: This didn't exactly work for me, but it did help me to realize what the problem was. ncdata was loaded into rstudio from an excel workbook. I don't know why that would be relevant, but by copying ncdata into a new dataframe without changing the column names and by referencing the new dataframe instead, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use `select` from the `dplyr` package in `tidyverse`. It can be simultaneously used to rename and subset.

```
library(tidyverse)

temp2 <- ncdata %>%
  select(year,
         report,
         prev_period_last_year = received)
```